# How to insert a link in a private message by code?

Tags: privatemsg

I am sending a message to some users when a specific function is created. However, the content of the message that I send is always in plain text, meaning that it does not render links. What can I do?

This is the function that I use:

```
$message="A user has requested to join your group ".$group->title.". You can go to the group's page now to approve or decline their request.";

privatemsg_new_thread(array($user), 'New membership request for '.$group->title, $message);
```

I would this to work:

```
$message="A user has requested to join your group ".l($group->title,'group/'.$group->gid).". You can go to the group's page now to approve or decline their request.";
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/900794) help?

Comment: Hi Jimmy, I am using a private message module function. Your link is to format a regular email. Thanks though.

Comment: Ah... sorry for mis-reading your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
function _send_notifications($entity, $recipient) {
    $params = set_params($recipient, $entity);
    $sent = privatemsg_new_thread(array($recipient), $params['message_subject'], trim(token_replace($params['message_body']))); 
}

function set_params($account, $entity) {
    if (isset($entity->nid) && $entity->type == 'entity_type') {
        $author = user_load($entity->uid); // Load the node author.
        $params = array(
            '!first_name' => $account->field_first_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'],
            '!last_name' => $account->field_last_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'],
            '!node_type' => drupal_ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $entity->type)),
            '!node_title' => $entity->title,
            '!node_url' => url(drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $entity->nid), array('absolute' => TRUE)),
        );
        $data['message_subject'] = t('New node type has been created');
        $data['message_body'] = t(
            "Dear !first_name !last_name,\na new !node_type has been posted with the title \"!node_title\".\n\nYou can view the post here:\n!node_url\n\n--  [site:name] team", $params
        );

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it, and it works. But I would prefer to avoid showing the full URL and put a hyperlinked phrase instead. I don't understand how url() displays the link, whereas l() displays the tags in plain text instead of the rendered link!